# Seperate linq results by first letter asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by

I have a linq query which returns results ordered by first letter. Is there a way to return the first letter before the group ordered by that letter? For instance;

```
**A**
Acountants
Apothecary
**B**
Basketball
Biscuits
```

and so on. I tried grouping my results like this;

```
  var companyquery = (from c in db.Categories
                            group c by c.Name.Substring(0, 1)
                                into cgroup
                                select new
                                {
                                    FirstLetter = cgroup.Key,
                                    Names = cgroup

                                }).OrderBy(letter => letter.FirstLetter);

        return View(companyquery);
```

but got error:

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type       'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.String]]', but       this dictionary requires a model item of type     'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NewAtAClick.Models.Category]'.'

So now I'm    using     orderby instead of group _ into _ . Here is my query;

```
   var companyquery = (from c in db.Categories
                            orderby c.Name.Substring(0, 1)
                            select c);
```

This returns them in alphebetical order. I tried saying

```
     letter1 = companyquery.ToString().SubString(0,1)
```

then

```
     return view(letter1 + companyquery.ToList());
```

But nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Paste your group into code as that should work fine but understand it won't be a straight list but sections ie groups

Comment: I've added the code I was using to group it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says it all. Your view expects a model of type `IEnumerable<Category>` but you passed in something else (in this case because you are creating a new anonymous type via the call to `select new { ... }`).

Instead you could declare a new type:

```
public class AlphabeticalMapping<T> {
    public char FirstLetter { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And change your query to return:

```
 var companyquery = (from c in db.Categories
                     group c by c.Name.Substring(0, 1)
                     into cgroup
                     select new AlphabeticalMapping<Category>() {
                         FirstLetter = cgroup.Key,
                         Items= cgroup.ToList()
                     }).OrderBy(mapping => mapping.FirstLetter);
```

And change your view to expect `IEnumerable<AlphabeticalMapping<Category>>`

Comment: Thanks for your help marcin. I'm a beginner and you've made clear what the error means rather than just giving me the answer, which is great! I have to leave the office unexpectedly so I'll try this tomorrow and comment on how I get on. Thanks again!

Comment: I too am just starting with C# and this really helped me out! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try this?

```
var companyquery = (from c in db.Categories
                        group c by c.Name.Substring(0, 1)
                            into cgroup
                            select new, 
                            {
                                FirstLetter = cgroup.Key,
                                Names = cgroup

                            })
                            .OrderBy(letter => letter.FirstLetter)
                            .ToDictionary(k => k.FirstLetter, e => e.Names);
```

Comment: `Dictionary<K,V>` doesn't guarantee the order in which it's key-value pairs get enumerated in. So the view might in fact lose the alphabetical ordering.

Comment: @Marcind, good point, but I guess I was under the impression from the error message that View required a dictionary.

Comment: @Marcind, Looks like your answer went a step further by saying the View should have a model of type `IEnumerable<AlphabeticalMappingCategory>`, so I'll upvote yours.